# How to detect Java agents, JVMTI, etc

Tags: java, security, agent, bytecode-manipulation, jvmti

How does one secure the Java environment when running on a machine you don't control?  What is to stop someone from creating a java agent or native JVMTI agent and dumping bytecode or re-writing classes to bypass licensing and/or other security checks?  Is there any way to detect if any agents are running from Java code?  From JNI?  From a JVMTI agent?

Comment: @Andrew Westberg: if you don't want people to inspect your code, make your code server-based.  Make computation happen on the server-side: no-one is reverse engineering GMail's server side code because it is, well, happening on the server side.  It may not be practical for you, but it is certainly for my company ;)

Comment: Bottom line: if you don't control the machine, you have no *real* control. There's just no way around that. You can throw some hurdles at guys trying to do that.. but I'm not convinced it'll be worth your effort.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't control the environment, then I'm sorry - you're really stuck.  Yes, you could look for trivial JVMTI agents via some sort of cmdline sniffing, but that's the least of your worries.  Think about java/lang/Classloader.defineClass() being compromised directly.  That's easy to do if you own the box - just replace the .class file in rt.jar. In fact, until JVMTI came around, that was a typical way that profilers and monitoring tools instrumented Java code.

Going back to JVMTI - the "Late attach" feature also allows for JVMTI agents to be loaded on the fly.  That might not have happened when you scanned the first time around.

Bottom line - if someone can change the bytes of the JRE on disk, they can do anything they want.  Is it ethical, no?  Can they get caught?  Possibly, but you'll never win the war.

Comment: I don't use ClassLoader.defineClass(), so I'm not vulnerable there.  I'm injecting bytecode directly into the native java.dll via JNI.

Comment: I don't see why.  What magic do you think your going via java.dll is doing?  I would imagine java.dll will turn around and call back in via java to do this, so I doubt your path to jvm.dll (where the JVM really sits) is as clean as you think.  But the point around not being able to trust remains: java.dll itself could be compromised as you don't own it.  Or jvm.dll.  Either could be replaced by "man in the middle" DLLs that monitor/manipulate all calls through them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I can go with a combination of checks inside some custom JNI native code.

1.) cmd line sniffing to search for agents.
2.) Ensure that the cmd-line parameter -XX:+DisableAttachMechanism exists. (this will prevent people from attaching to my running VM)

Answer (score 0):

I remember I once made almost a silent Java Agent. I guess you better look for port scanners or something around that.

Answer (score 0):

Java 2 security, signing of jars etc, gives some level of control over what gets loaded into your application.

However in the end if a malicious person has access to a machine such that they can write to disk then in all probability they have plenty of capacity to do harm without resorting to clever Java hacks.

Turn this round, in any language what can you do to detect Trojans?

Careful access control to the machines you care about is non-trivial but essential if you are serious about such issues. Security specialists may seem paranoid, but that often means that they really understand the risks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't control the platform, you can't control the software upon it.

Even if you could shut down all the avenues of inspection you've listed, Java is open source.  They could just take the source code and recompile it with the necessary changes built-in.

Also, try to remember that while it is your code, it's their machine.  They have a right to inspect your code to verify that running it on their machine does what they expect it to do, and doesn't perform "extra" actions which they might find undesirable.  Less trustworthy companies in the past have scanned for non-relevant files, copied sensitive information back to their home servers, etc.

Comment: I don't buy the whole "they have the right" stuff.  At least not according to current US copyright law.  If I'm issuing them a license to use my software, I need to have some comfort that they can't simply bypass my licensing on the Java platform.

Comment: Copyright means they can't make unauthorized copies, not that they can't inspect the original.  A license may put terms on the use of the software, and probably should include clauses restricting reverse engineering, circumvention of licensing code, etc.  However, you are licensing the use of your software, not the use of their hardware or JVM.  That said, it's a legal solution, not a technical one.  Technically, it can't be done unless you provide a closed hardware solution with signed BIOS and encrypted hard disks, and even then (XBOX) a small error on your part might open up the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the command line and see, if there are any "-agent" parameters. All profilers, debuggers and other code modificators use this for introspection. You could also check for unusual jars on the bootclasspath, since those might also provide a threat (but be aware that you then also must deliver a custom JVM, since some software like Quicktime adds itself to the bootclasspath of ALL java apps running... (I couldn't belive my eyes when I saw that...))

Comment: I like the idea of scanning the cmd line and looking for -agent.  What about dynamically attaching agents?  Is there some way to detect those from native code?

Comment: Have a look at how visualvm attaches to a running JVM and allows for on-the-fly profiling.  Command line analysis will never catch that.

Comment: For visual vm to attach JMX must be enabled. He could check for that, too.

Comment: What command line? In Java you have no access to the arguments given to the VM.

Comment: @Daniel No, visualvm can attach to any normally started Hotspot JVM

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: This may be the case today. My post is 8 years old ;)

Comment: @Daniel To my understanding visualvm has always supported the Java 6+ Attach API.  Including 8 years ago.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Okey, maybe I just didn't know there was a way these years ago. Lets assume you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is a loosing battle.

Have a look at how visualvm in the Sun JDK works and how it can attach to a running process and redefine whatever it pleases.  It is extremely hard to detect that in a portable way, and unless you can do so, you might as well give up on this approach.

The question is, what is it you want to avoid?

Comment: -XX:+DisableAttachMechanism looks like it can prevent dynamic attaching.

Comment: @AndrewWestberg Is there a way to disable the attach mechanism programatically from within the Java app itself after it has launched?  Perhaps via jmx?

Comment: @opeongo This question is 8 years old, so I haven't been working in this environment for some time. I'm not aware of any way to disable attaching other than the command line.